# Where is the datamodel in this example typescript (dot net example)?

Tags: c#, angular

I'm working on learning/understanding TypeScript today.  I created a new angular project in VS2017 and have the "default" pages that come up.  One of the pages is pulling data from a controller seen here:

```
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-fetch-data',
      templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
    })
    export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

    constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
 }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
  dateFormatted: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

This is the data component that is automatically created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LearnAngular.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {
        private static string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("d"),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            });
        }

        public class WeatherForecast
        {
            public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
            public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }

            public int TemperatureF
            {
                get
                {
                    return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it's displayed, it's using this in the .html file:

```
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Temp. (C)</th>
      <th>Temp. (F)</th>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>{{ forecast.dateFormatted }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, searching my code I don't see where forecast is defined as a model?  Is it not a data model?

This is the line in question:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
```

I see "forecasts" defined in the "fetch-data.components.ts" file, but no reference to "forecast" which is what I would expect a data model to be.  Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in C# as

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF
    {
        get
        {
            return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        }
    }
}
```

and defined in the front-end as

```
interface WeatherForecast {
  dateFormatted: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

`forecasts` is being set to the result of the API call, an array of `WeatherForecast` instances. `forecast` is a local variable within the `*ngFor` loop.